Package Upload Error Due to Low Test Coverage Despite High Org Code Coverage
I’m facing a challenging issue while trying to upload a managed package in Salesforce. Despite having an overall organisation code coverage of 85%, I receive an error stating that the average test coverage across all Apex classes and triggers in the package is only 40%, while at least 75% coverage is required. Here are the details:
Package upload error: "Average test coverage across all Apex classes and triggers is 40%. At least 75% test coverage is required."

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on this.

See this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386327&type=1

I resolved my package upload issue, I missed to add some of test classes to package, so that it throws low coverage . I added all of my test classes to the package and uploaded successfully.
